# What is correct syntax for Knockout.js css binding?

Tags: knockout.js

I need to use few binding properties in the same element and my syntax look fine for me, but VS said that ":" and "}" expected. What is wrong with my markup?

```
<div class="list-group" data-bind="foreach: histories, css: { bg-danger: $data.IsRead() == false}" id="histories">
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are essentially defining an object in your binding.  It's as if you have written in regular javascript:

```
var css = {
    bg-danger: $data.IsRead() == false
}
```

Now you should know that hyphens are not legal in the name of an object literal, at least not written out like that.  You have to quote it.

Change your binding to:

```
<div class="list-group" id="histories"
     data-bind="foreach: histories,
                css: { 'bg-danger': $data.IsRead() == false }">
```

p.s.,

```
$data.IsRead() == false
```

is better written out as

```
!$data.IsRead()
```

Answer (score 3):

The dash in your class requires you to use quotes, e.g.:

```
css: { 'bg-danger': $data.IsRead() == false}
```

See [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vvbk8/1/).